# Is there any public data source for LAS 1.4 or at least point format 4 or above?

Tags: geospatial

I have looked at https://opentopography.org/tags/data.
The data I obtained from https://opentopography.org/tags/data was in 1.3. 
  Some one told that it should be available at usgs site but I felt lost at the site. If you had success in getting the aforementioned data at usgs or some other site please share your experience.

Comment: Hi @qqqqq, what exactly do you mean by LAS?  Is this a specific dataset or do you mean some form of remotely sensed lidar data?

Comment: @sboysel It is a format for 3d point could and some additional information. You can read ore about it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAS_file_format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it from 
 https://cteco.uconn.edu/data/download/flight2016/index.htm

There is drop down to select a city. 
I selected the first city Andover. 
On the right of the map a table with 4 columns heading appear.
The last column  has las data. 
I selected one element ( clocked on the link) from the last column. 
I popped up a window titled "Results"> This window has two tabs: "Town" and "Tile". 
I clicked on "Tile" tab
Then there are links for Tiff , DEM etc . Among them is LAS.
I clicked on the LAS.
It downloaded a zip file.
By uncompressing the zip file, I got my las file. 
The version of the downloaded file was 1.4  and point format was 6.